# Why did JSON.parse() start giving a different output all of a sudden?

Tags: javascript, flask, jinja2

I am using Flask and Jinja 2 in combination with Javascript. I am passing CSVs using pandas

To load variables into javascript, I pass them from the backend

```
def index():
  df = pd.load_csv(...)
  return render_template('..', df=df.to_json(orient='records')
```

and in the front-end I have:

```
var df = JSON.parse({{ df |tojson}});
... use df
```

Prior to today this always returned as array of 1 record of json like so:

```
[
{
  "ID": [101, 102, 103],
  "Person": ["Alice", "Bob", "Jimmy"]
}
]
```

I always found this an odd way of doing it, but it did not make a huge difference.
But today for whatever reason it returns what you would expect:

```
[
{
  'ID': 101,
  'Person': 'Alice'
},
... other records
]
```

I have no idea why it decided to change and am worried that it could randomly change back in forth in production.
I did not update flask, or jinja, but maybe Firefox automatically updated. I have no problem if it stays this way, but I am scratching my head as to why it did change. Can anyone enlighten me as I can not seem to find any answers from an internet search.

using 
`
`df.to_json(orient='columns')` does not have the output i was expecting? What gives?

Edit: Missing a "

Comment: JSON.parse is fairly dumb. It only parses the JSON string you pass to it. You obviously passed a very different JSON string before. So the problem is not in javascript or with JSON.parse but with your python code

Comment: Maybe, but i always have done df.to_json(orient='records') so I do not see how that would affect it.